# percentage formula in crystal report 8.5

Tags: vba

I am doing one project using vb6.0+access+crystal report8.5

some error occur during the crystal report.

Query Name

seqquery:

```
SELECT segment_trans.division_name, sum(segment_trans.Total_value) AS total, 
       division_master.Target
FROM segment_trans, division_master
GROUP BY segment_trans.division_name, division_master.Target;
```

crystal report percentage formula:

```
{(seqquery.total * 100) / seqquery.Target }
```

Error: This field name is not known.

**note: Total_value and Target field's datatype "Text"**

how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
sum(segment_trans.Total_value) AS total,
```

To this:

```
sum(segment_trans.Total_value) total,
```

Comment: Explanation:  SQL syntax varies between applications.  Some kinds use AS for alias, others leave it out.